# How to store my translation texts from firestore collection into the localizedValue set?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, internationalization

i'm trying to store my texts for internationalization from firestore collection into the _localizedValue set of the Localization class but it seems that the constructor is never called, i don't get it.

> [EDIT] our client has to be able to modify/create the translation, so
>   json file is not an option

I took the code from [Flutter's github](https://github.com/flutter/website/blob/master/examples/internationalization/minimal/lib/main.dart)  which is explained  [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization)

The collection structure i like so:

```
input.placeholder.name : {i18n : { 'en': String, 'fr': String, 'es': String}}
```

The only solution i found for the moment is to call firestore for each translation i need, doing this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('texts')
    .document('input.placeholder.city').get().then(
        (item){
            setState(() {
                inputtext = item.data['i18n'][lang];
            }
        ); 
    }
);
```

but i don't think it's the right solution

this is my Localization class actually:

```
class Localization {
    final Locale locale;

    Localization(this.locale) {
        print("Constructor");
        buildLocalized();
    }

    static Map<String, Map<String, String>> _localizedValues = {
        'es': {},
        'ca': {},
        'en': {},
        'fr': {}
    };

    buildLocalized() async {
        return await FireStoreCalls()
            .getTexts()
            .then((item) => item.documents.forEach((f) {
                print(f);
                _localizedValues.update(
                    'es', (Map val) => {f.documentID: f.data['i18n']['es']});
                _localizedValues.update(
                    'ca', (Map val) => {f.documentID: f.data['i18n']['ca']});
                _localizedValues.update(
                    'fr', (Map val) => {f.documentID: f.data['i18n']['fr']});
                _localizedValues.update(
                    'en', (Map val) => {f.documentID: f.data['i18n']['en']});
            }));
    }

    String translate(key) {
        if (_localizedValues[locale.languageCode][key] != null) {
            return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode][key];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    static Future<String> of(BuildContext context, String key) async {
         return Localizations.of<Localization>(context, 
             Localization).translate(key);
    }
}
```

I need my collection to be stored in the _localizedValues set but calling buildLocalized() method in the constructor doesn't do anything.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why are you need to get your localizations from firebase? 
I think you should do it in advance. You need to hold the all translations in your app. Or you can download the `.arb` file that you need for translations, but anyway , you have to write your translations in your "`localization.dart`"
I can give an example but I need to be sure that I'm not missing something.

Comment: Yes sorry indeed, forgot this part, our client has to be able to modify/create the translations so we thought that firebase was the best solution

Comment: I think there is no way to do that, because you need to write `getter`s for your localizations and generate `.arb` files based on your `localizations.dart/locales.dart` ( the file where you are writing localizations ). In the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#appendix-using-the-dart-intl-tools), there is also telling about it.

Comment: hmmm, yeah but i'm not using the intl package, i'm using flutter_localizations package

Comment: Then the only thing that I can suggest you, is to get all firebase data related to your translations, before the app starts and convert them to JSON from where you will get your translations.

Answer (score 0):

One way of approaching this issue is by generating a localization file from the stored values in Firstore to the supported format that you prefer i.e. json, yaml. You can then host the localization file and load the hosted file from the Flutter app using the [flutter_i18n](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_i18n) plugin.

For example if the translation files are located at https://example.com/static/en.json, the config should look like:

```dart
localizationsDelegates: [
    FlutterI18nDelegate(translationLoader: 
    NetworkFileTranslationLoader(baseUri: Uri.https("example.com", "static")),
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
],
```